# Number guessing game in JOptionPane, JPanel is not showing up(Java)

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So I made a number guessing game program with the use of *JOptionPane*, my problem is that when I run the program no window gets displayed and the program would end even though there's no error when I build it.

My code so far is this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestNo4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random ranNum = new Random();
        int secretNum = ranNum.nextInt(100) + 1;
        int guess = 0;
        int guessNo = 0;
        int guessLimit = 5;

        JTextField numUserIn = new JTextField(5);
        JPanel getInput = new JPanel();
        getInput.add(new JLabel("Enter you guess(Limit of 5 guesses)"));
        getInput.add(numUserIn);

        for (int countGuess = 0; countGuess == guessLimit; countGuess++) {
            int numInput = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, getInput,
                    "Guess number " + countGuess, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (numInput == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                guess = Integer.parseInt(numUserIn.getText());
                if (guess == secretNum) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations!!",
                            "Got it in " + countGuess + " tries",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }
                if (countGuess == guessLimit) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Sorry, No more guesses left.", "The number is"
                                    + secretNum,
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }
                if (guess > secretNum) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hint",
                            "Try something lower.",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hint",
                            "Try something higher.",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: `countGuess==guessLimit`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yeah sorry for that, already changed my program thanks to Vivek Singh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below line and would work

```
for (int countGuess = 0; countGuess == guessLimit; countGuess++) {
```

with

```
for (int countGuess = 0; countGuess <= guessLimit; countGuess++) {
```

The problem is with the termination condition. Since it only check fo equal values it never runs the loop.

Comment: Thanks, will remember that.

Comment: Can you mark this as an answer if it solver your issue. Thanks:)\